# What was the inspiration for Dr. Manhattan's "time travel" abilities?

Tags: dc, watchmen

In *Watchmen* and most of its adaptations, Doctor Manhattan has the power to experience all of his life simultaneously. He can be at the formation of the Crimebusters and at his breakup with Silk Spectre II at the same time.

I am aware that DC's Captain Atom was the inspiration for Doctor Manhattan's character as a whole, but what was the inspiration for Dr. Manhattan's time powers? I was reading Kurt Vonnegut's *Slaughterhouse-Five*, where the protagonist Billy Pilgrim experiences time in a similar way to Doctor Manhattan, but that book was written in the late 1960s.

Has Alan Moore said what the inspiration for that ability was?

Comment: He's certainly read his share of Vonnegut. And not just the usual tourist-attractions like Slaughterhouse-Five, some obscure stuff too; https://www.comicsbeat.com/alan-moores-secret-qa-cult-exposed-part-ii-youll-gasp-when-you-see-what-he-told-them/

Comment: Vonnegut's _Sirens of Titan_ has the enigmatic Winston Niles Rumfoord, since you mention Vonnegut.

Comment: I don't know if there's a literary inspiration, but Dr Manhattan is generally based on the developing fields of General Relativity and Quantum Mechanics in the 30s and 40s.